# Python: Seaborn: Sorting based on Y Axis instead of X Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I have the following data

```
Index   ID          Amount
360822  96996965    452456
385861  97122362    388764
574798  17681255    428909
633610  17841255    425101
806930  18373304    1049287
814809  18406524    614720
877178  15683610    485065
996266  16123139    434727
1279340 16934859    403961
1356620 17167658    544570
```

`Index` column is the index of dataframe. I have plotted the ID (X Axis) vs amount (Y Axis) in the graph. ID gets sorted in ascending order.

`import seaborn as sns`

`plot = sns.barplot(x='ID', y='Amount', data=df)`

Is there a way to sort the plot with respect to Y axis so that the ID with largest `Amount` is on the leftmost and one with smallest value of `Amount` is in right most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an `order=` parameter to barplot to change the order of the bars. If you sort your dataframe in descending `Amount`s and get the corresponding `ID`s then you can use that in the call to `barplot`

```
plot_order = df.sort_values(by='Amount', ascending=False).ID.values
plot = sns.barplot(x='ID', y='Amount', data=df, order=plot_order)
```

[image]